# Rails Tutorial - debugging bundle exec rake test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org

I'm a new user, so please don't kill me. I have been working through the Rails Tutorial by Michael Hartl, Chapter 9, with some success. In running the "bundle exec rake test" commands, I have encountered 3 errors. These do not affect the status of the tests, so my tests are still red or green per Mr. Hartl's specifications, but there are some issues with the appearance of my pages on the web, and I'm concerned that the errors might snowball.

Does anyone know what seems to be going on here? I've hand keyed his code blocks in the Cloud9 IDE to the best of my ability, so the syntax should be correct with 100% accuracy. My background is Java and C#, and these remind me of compiler errors.

**1) Error:**

```
UsersLoginTest#test_login_with_valid_information_followed_by_logout: NoMethodError: undefined method `forget' for nil:NilClass
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:41:in `forget'
    app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb:48:in `log_out'
    app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:18:in `destroy'
    test/integration/users_login_test.rb:33:in `block in <class:UsersLoginTest>'
```

**2) Error:**

```
UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_a_non-admin: SyntaxError: /home/ubuntu/workspace/sample_app/app/views/users/index.html.erb:12: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting end-of-input
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:31:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'
```

**3) Error:**

```
UsersIndexTest#test_index_as_admin_including_pagination_and_delete_links:
NoMethodError: undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass
    test/test_helper.rb:19:in `log_in_as'
    test/integration/users_index_test.rb:11:in `block in <class:UsersIndexTest>'

37 runs, 84 assertions, 0 failures, 3 errors, 0 skips
```

**test/models/test_helper.rb**

```
<% provide(:title, 'All users') %>

<h1>All users</h1>

<%= will_paginate %>

<ul class="users">
  <%= render @users %>
  <% end %>
</ul>

<%= will_paginate %>
```

**test/integration/users_index_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersIndexTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @admin     = users(:michael)
    @non_admin = users(:archer)
  end

  test "index as admin including pagination and delete links" do
    log_in_as(@user)
    get users_path
    assert_template 'users/index'
    assert_select 'div.pagination'
    first_page_of_users = User.paginate(page: 1)
    first_page_of_users.each do |user|
      assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: user.name
      unless user == @admin
        assert_select 'a[href=?]', user_path(user), text: 'delete',
                                                    method: :delete

      end
    end
    assert_difference 'User.count', -1 do
      delete user_path(@non_admin)
    end
  end

  test "index as a non-admin" do
    log_in_as(@non_admin)
    get users_path
    assert_select 'a', text: 'delete', count: 0
  end
end
```

**test/integration/users_login_test.rb**

```
require 'test_helper'

class UsersLoginTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  def setup
    @user = users(:michael)
  end

  test "login with invalid information" do  
    get login_path
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    post login_path, session: { email: "", password: "" }
    assert_template 'sessions/new'
    assert_not flash.empty?
    get root_path
    assert flash.empty?
  end

  test "login with valid information followed by logout" do
    get login_path
    post login_path, session: { email: @user.email, password: 'password' }
    assert is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to @user
    follow_redirect!
    assert_template 'users/show'
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path, count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user)
    delete logout_path
    assert_not is_logged_in?
    assert_redirected_to root_url
    # Simulate a user clicking logout in a second window
    delete logout_path
    follow_redirect!
    assert_select "a[href=?]", login_path
    assert_select "a[href=?]", logout_path,       count: 0
    assert_select "a[href=?]", user_path(@user),  count: 0
  end

  test "login with remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
    assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end

  test "login without remembering" do
    log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '0')
    assert_nil cookies['remember_token']
  end
end
```

Comment: We need to see some code in order to help you out.

Comment: Could you add the tests please?

Comment: Thanks. My source code is basically the same code verbatim out of the book. I have spot-checked for typo's.

Comment: I've posted the source code re: test errors. Thanks for offering to help!

Answer (score 0):

Error #1: you need to provide more details. But the error trace indicates that something goes wrong when you call the logout_path with the delete method for the second time. Can you provide your `sessions_helper.rb` file ?

Error #2 seems to come from the `index.html.erb` template. Can you post the code?

Error #3: you are trying to log in as `@user`, but this instance variable is not defined. Change the line `log_in_as(@user)` to: `log_in_as(@admin)`.

Also, take care that your test `"login with remembering"` is wrong, it should be:

```
test "login with remembering" do
  log_in_as(@user, remember_me: '1')
  assert_not_nil cookies['remember_token']
end
```